# Why do I get an error for the first statement, but not the second one? (C++ substring)

Tags: c++, string, substring, substr

The goal is to get the first, middle, and last name initials each followed by a period.

```
string first;
string middle;
string last;
string result;
```

The expression is typed in the string result.

**I typed:**

```
result = first[0] + "." + middle[0] + "." last[0] + ".";
```

**And received an the following error:**

```
invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

**But when I remove the "." for the above statement, it compiles without any error.**

The **solution** ended up being:

```
result = first.substr(0,1) + "." + middle.substr(0,1) + "." last.substr(0,1) + ".";
```

So my question is that, why do I get a compile error when I add `.` with `string[0]`, but not when I add `.` with `string.substr(0,1)`?

Comment: `[0]` gives you a character and `substr` gives you a `string`.  The `+` only works as a concatenate operator if you have a `string` object in the expression.

Comment: The code shown can't produce the error shown. The error message is complaining about concatenating a `const char*` pointer with a `const char[2]` array. The string literal `"."` is the `const char[2]`, but `string::operator[]` returns a `char&`, not a `const char*`. There is no `const char*` anywhere in this code, so what is the compiler actually complaining about? Unless this is not your *real* code. Also, the code shown is missing syntax elements. There is a missing semicolon after `string middle`, and there is a `+` missing before `last[0]`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Apologies for the tardy response. Yes, there should be a semicolon in there which I forgot to type when writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first[0] + "."
```

In this expression:

1. `first` is a `std::string`.
2. Therefore, `first[0]` is a `char` (some immaterial technical details omitted).
3. `"."` is a `char [2]` (an array of two `char` values).

In C++, it is illegal to add a `char` value to a `char [2]`, you can't just add `char` to an array. That's simply not allowed in C++. There are various rules about what you can do to what else in C++. You can add numerical values to other numerical values. You can add an integer value to a pointer. Finally, a class can define its own `+` operator. That's pretty much it. None of this applies to this expression, hence the compilation error.

Now, if you go back and reread the actual error message that your compiler showed you, it should make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This does not do what you think (you should have tested it):

```
first[0] + middle[0] + last[0]
```

Each of those is a single character, and in C++, single characters are essentially one-byte integers.  So adding them just adds their ASCII values (see https://www.asciitable.com/ for those numbers).

`first.substr(0,1)` gives you a string, and strings can be concatenated with `+`.

Another way to do what you want is:

```
result.append(first[0]);
result.append('.');
result.append(middle[0]);
result.append('.');
result.append(last[0]);
```

That just appends one character at a time.  You can also pass strings like `result.append("...")` if you want.  The `'` single quote is what makes a literal `char` instead of a literal string (array of chars).

Answer (score 0):

While your question was answered very well, here are other options that I would prefer over `substr`.

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::ostringstream compose;
compose << first[0] << "." << middle[0] << "." << last[0] << ".";
std::string result = compose.str();
```

or also

```
string result = string(first[0]) + "." + string(middle[0]) + "." + string(last[0]) + ".";
```